# Android com.google.android.material.chip.Chip is not visible when Dark theme enabled

Tags: android, android-chips

My current Android application supports Dark theme by employing the standard theming colours for text and backgrounds.

e.g.

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/colorSurface"
android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
android:tint="?attr/colorOnSurface"
```

Which all works fine in both Light and Dark mode

However I have now tried to employ

```
com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
```

and in Dark mode the "Chip" is not visible, only the chip text

here is my layout.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/tags_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/colorSurface"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/chip_text" />

    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

In light mode, the Card is White and the Chip background is light grey
In Dark mode, the Card is Dark Grey and the Chip background appears to be the exact same colour.
When I click on the chip I can see the ripple in dark mode.

What theming am i missing that will allow me to see the chip both in Dark and Light mode?

My App theme is defined as follows:-

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimations</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryVariantColor</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondaryVariantColor</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@style/TextAppearance.Literal</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
</style>
```

In Light Mode the chip is visible

[image]

In Dark Mode the chip is not visible

[image]

Comment: It should depend by the [Elevation Overlays](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Dark.md#elevation-overlays). Try to use an higher elevation on the chip.